# How to display the title in detail view corresponding to the row selected in the table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, title

I am new to iphone development. I am displaying an array of data in a table. Upon clicking the row, it navigates to the corresponding detail view. I want to display a title in the detail view corresponding to the row selected in the table.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    if([[tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Display The Text"])
    {  
        secondviewcontroller *second= [[secondviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
    }

    if([[tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"iPhone Image"])
    {  
        thirdviewcontroller *third= [[thirdviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"thirdviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:third animated:YES];
    }
}
```

If "display the text" is selected, the corresponding navigated view should have it's title set to "display the text" below the navigation bar as title for a header and if "iphone image" is selected, the corresponding view should display the title has "iphone image" below the navigation bar as title for header.

Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your secondviewcontroller and thirdviewcontroller declare a string property, and add the following code. It should work fine.

```
if([[tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Display The Text"])
    {  
        secondviewcontroller *second= [[secondviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:                          
                           @"secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];  
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
         second.lblTitle = [tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


    if([[tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"iPhone Image"])
    {  
        thirdviewcontroller *third= [[thirdviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"thirdviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:third animated:YES];
         third.lblTitle = [tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your view controller's title before pushing it on the navigation stack. In your case:

```
second.title = [tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: This will display the title in navigation bar but i want the title to be displayed below the navigation bar( like title in titleforHeader method)

Comment: Alright, sorry that I misread your question. Declare a string property in your detail view controllers and assign the title to it when you create the controller. Then put a UILabel on the view and in the view controller's viewDidLoad, assign the string as the label text. I don't really see what the problem is here.